# Incoming filebeats data with additional lookup and insert as nested

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am using a tool which inserts documents into elastic using filebeats. However I want to enrich this data based off data from an existing index.

For example incoming data would be an event described as:

```
{
    player1: "Luigi",
    player2: "Mario".
    game: "Tennis"
}
```

And I would have an existing index which contains data like:

```
[{
     name: "Luigi",
     age: 26,
     gender: "M"
},
{
     name: "Mario",
     age: 32,
     gender: "M"
}]
```

What I want would be a way that when I insert the event that it automatically inserts the relational data from the other index as nested. So expected result (or something similar) would be:

```
{
    player1: {
         name: "Luigi",
         age: 26,
         gender: "M"
    },
    player2: {
         name: "Mario",
         age: 32,
         gender: "M"
    },
    game: "Tennis"
}
```

I don't really have access to edit these incoming events directly with this data, so I was curious if there's a way to have elasticsearch do this automatically?

I guess there's a way to do this via logstash, but I was hoping to avoid logstash. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Good news!
Elasticsearch enrich process can fit your use case :)
[image]
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html

Here is a good official example to test it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html

Comment: oh man, this looks promising! will need to do a bit more research